# Unit test AWS DynamoDB take a lot of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb, xunit, serverless-framework

I do run some test against an AWS Dynamo DB. I got some integration tests and I need to speed them up. SetupTableAsync takes ~10 seconds and the code is in my constructor so it runs on every instance/test. 
Is it possible to use the same IAmazonDynamoDB instance on every test?

```
private string TableName { get; }
IAmazonDynamoDB DDBClient { get; }

public FunctionTest()
{
    this.TableName = "Table-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    this.DDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

    SetupTableAsync().Wait();
}

//... some tests

private async Task SetupTableAsync()
{
    var request = new CreateTableRequest
    {
        TableName = this.TableName,
        ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
        {
            ReadCapacityUnits = 2,
            WriteCapacityUnits = 2
        },
        KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
        {
            new KeySchemaElement
            {
                KeyType = KeyType.HASH,
                AttributeName = UserFunctions.ID_QUERY_STRING_NAME
            }
        },
        AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>
        {
            new AttributeDefinition
            {
                AttributeName = UserFunctions.ID_QUERY_STRING_NAME,
                AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
            }
        }
    };

    await this.DDBClient.CreateTableAsync(request);

    var describeRequest = new DescribeTableRequest { TableName = this.TableName };
    DescribeTableResponse response = null;
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        response = await this.DDBClient.DescribeTableAsync(describeRequest);
    } while (response.Table.TableStatus != TableStatus.ACTIVE);
}
```

This code is from the 'AWS Serverless Application with tests' template in Visual Studio.

Comment: You might want to look int DynamoDB Local (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) as well.

Comment: You can't call it a "unit test" if you're not mocking DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xunit you can [share the `IAmazonDynamoDB` instance across tests](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html)

Answer (score 1):

Similiar to Dunedan's suggestion:

In these scenarios, I typically rely on DynamoDB Local: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

I like this for a few reasons:

- This also supports multiple tests running in parallel (in the case of multiple developers working on the project).
- More cost effective
- If you use the in memory switch, it does not persist the data after you kill the process.
- Much more performant!
- Allows you to run the tests in CI environments (without providing Access Keys for privileges of creating / tearing down tables etc)

Comment: But DynamoDB will only work in my local enviroment? Because I'm pushing my code to VSTS and there will my test run as well. Is it possible to solve that?

Comment: Haven't used VSTS, but in other CI tools such as Travis CI and Team City, I've either started a seperate DynamoDB Local process on test startup, or used something like Docker to start it up (saves you from installed java).